# RabbitMQ - Find out on publisher side that a message has been acknowledged by the consumer(s)

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am using RabbitMQ as a MQ broker. Is it possible to get a notification that a certain message has been acknowledged by all queues? That is, if it was sent to 5 queues, we get a notification after the acknowledgment of the last/5th consumer.

I know you can introduce `reply-to` queues, but that's not what I am looking for. I don't want to force the consumer to send *an acknowledgment message* to some queue after acknowledgment.

Is it also possible to continue this follow-up after a broker and/or publisher restart?

Answer (score 2):

**No, it is not possible as you state it.**

You cannot, from the publisher side, know whether a message has been ACK'd at the consumer side, and in most patterns it's not really something you'd want anyway.

You can, however, use [Publisher Confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms). These would inform the publisher that the message has been routed to all the bound queues.

There are several mechanisms for [data safety](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html) on both the publisher and consumer side. You would normally trust that the broker does not miss messages in between, the same way you trust that a database will hold the records over time.

If nevertheless your workflow requires that your publisher side is informed about the completion of a complex distributed task, and you *really* can't get away with [fire and forget](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/conversation/FireAndForget.html), then you will need to implement that response yourself, normally by means of an additional message.